# paper-drawer-toggle does not close menu after clicking

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, aurelia

I am using polymer and aurelia and have a menu that opens from the side. But after I click on an item in the menu when in mobile, it does not close automatically.

```
<paper-item if.bind="!authenticated" class="login" style="padding-left:10px">
    <a paper-drawer-toggle href="/login" class="nav-link">
        <span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span>
        <span if.bind="fullmenu" class="nav-item">Login</span>
    </a>
</paper-item>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this was the full solution:

```
<paper-item if.bind="!authenticated" class="login" style="padding-left:10px">
   <a paper-drawer-toggle href="/login" class="nav-link" click.delegate="close()">
    <span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span>
    <span if.bind="fullmenu" class="nav-item">Login</span>
   </a>
</paper-item>
```

and then this is the JavaScript

```
close() {
    if (!this.widescreen) {
        let drawer = document.getElementById('drawerPanel');
        drawer.closeDrawer();
    }
}
```

This is the link to the Polymer doc we found the answer we needed
https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-drawer-panel/paper-drawer-panel#methods

Comment: I've made this one the best answer because this is the solution that actually fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get `paper-drawer-toggle` to work, and had to create a function to handle it instead;

```
close() {
    let drawer = document.getElementById('drawerPanel');
    drawer.toggle();
    return true;
}
```

Then just add the function to the `click.trigger`;

```
<paper-item if.bind="!authenticated" class="login" style="padding-left:10px">
    <a paper-drawer-toggle href="/login" class="nav-link">
        <span class="fa fa-sign-in"></span>
        <span if.bind="fullmenu" class="nav-item">Login</span>
    </a>
</paper-item>
```

Comment: This works great. The only problem was that drawer.toggle() is not defined for that element. What I instead needed was drawer.closeDrawer() and drawer.openDrawer(). When I did that, it was all good.